# An earth-like society with popular submarine travel

Tags: science-based, technology, ocean

So I have recently been reading the new issue of "Just like us" from Feb 2245, the one that features the plane Aurora on its frontpage. I know that we've made a contact with these guys a while ago, but I just got a chance to actually learn about them. You know, so many Earth-like planets have been discovered in the last 50 years, hard to keep track of all of them.

So, what some of you may already know that, but let me just recap what I have learnt from the magazine.

- Aurora measure 0.974 on the Kepler scale, so its size, composition, atmosphere etc. are very much Earth-like. Well, maybe some rare-earth elements are not so rare-aurora ones
- Aurorians are pretty much humans, modulo nail and eye color and somewhat less aggressive demenaour
- their development matches ours almost toe to toe

What I have found as being one of the most interesting points though is the following: before making it to the space, Aurorians were very much fond of the underwater travel. This is unfortunately where my subscription to "Just like us" ended just half of the article into (I have already used all of mine 7.5 free articles per month), and I still have like so many questions.

1. What's the reason these guys have preferred the submarine travel to the surface one? I have heard that some of the oceans there feature extremely rough seas with strong storms and breaking waves. Could that really have been the reason for prefer going under water? Also, why would an Earth-like planet have such conditions since we don't see them on our planet I guess.
2. From my understanding, strong materials like titan etc. are quite easy to get on Aurora, so I guess going deep is not a problem for them in terms of the submarine body. Same applies to the energy sources, apparently they have discovered efficient nuclear energy usage before even learning to fly. Would easier availability of elements that are rare on our plane help the Aurorians also in building nice transparent parts of their submarines to have an accidental ability to observe their reach marine life?
3. Speaking of the marine life. I saw a drawing there picturing a submarine cruise ship where people would gather in the observatory hall of it while it was drifting by the steep slope of a reef full of fish and corals on the depth of several hundred feet from what the water color suggested. Won't the storms be a problem for the marine life at such depths?
4. Can it be the case that these storms also prevented Aurorians to cross them by air until the moment that have developed an easy ability to go through space?
5. A bit out of space, but as you might have guessed, I do consider going there maybe the next year. I'd love to have a nice underwater trip, but I'm also a big fun of the hydrofoil travel. I was wondering, could that be the case that Aurorians submarines feature foils so that if they know the seas above are not too rough, they go up and ride on the surface for a while?

Grateful for your thoughts guys!

Comment: @moderator there are a lot of questions on this website that ask about a given concept from different angles, they receive good answers and are not closed. This is  a question on a specific topic

Comment: Right of the bat if you get a little bit under the surface, surface conditions disappear.

Comment: You've enumerated at least five questions, on disparate topics, only _united_ by the setting, not the topic.  You could create a quick stat block for the setting, and then ask the relevant questions in _separate_ posts, and thereby adhere to site guidelines.  As the question currently appears, the closure is valid.

Comment: The storm thing is plausible: 100 feet below the surface, storms aren't felt much, and 500 feet below they have no effect at all. Reference: https://www.seasteading.org/the-seasteading-institute-policy-on-submersible-seasteads/

Comment: 2. titanium is not a great idea for submarines because it fatigues worse than steel from multiple compressions. They're just about workable, and some were made like the K-222, but engineers decided to pursue steel insteal

Comment: @wokopa the main problem with titanium submarines is the fact it's very difficult infrastructure to set up needed to make them due to the problem of titanium being extremely difficult to work & needing a lot of specialized equipment, after that's dealt with it can offer a significant performance advantage in either speed or dive depth. in total 12 were built by the soviets. In the end they stopped because only 1 yard could build them & only to a rather limited size more than any other reason. if they were more common that issue wouldn't be so much of a problem.

Comment: Titanium is more susceptible to work-hardening than steel is. An operational strain of submarines is that they get squeezed every bit they go down, unsqueezed every time they go up. The highly-advanced nature of Russian metallurgy allowed them to be a bit ahead on things like titanium submarines (and more recently, hypersonic missiles), but they didn't pursue that development.